# How to run a maven build command using DSL script in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to run a job through DSL script in jenkins. I am new to jenkins. Basically I want to run maven command to run my tests.

How to run maven command using DSL scripts.

Command: `mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @registration"`

[image]

Here is the DSL scripts.But getting error.

[image]

Comment: The `mvn` command doesn't really seem to be running. What happens if you do this instead: `shell('mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @registration"')`

Comment: Which version of Cucumber are you using?

Comment: Thanks for reply @MB I am getting error after trying shell('mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @registration"')




Processing provided DSL script
ERROR: (script, line 1) No signature of method: script.Job() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, script$_run_closure1) values: [Example, script$_run_closure1@3d53ac2]
Possible solutions: job(java.lang.String), job(java.lang.String, groovy.lang.Closure), run(), run(), any(), ivyJob(java.lang.String)
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: i am using cucumber version 7.8.1 @M.P.Korstanje

Comment: Cucumber doesn't have `cucumber.options` any more. You can use individual properties https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-core#properties-environment-variables-system-options